# Why is Hibernate response not reflected when making direct changes in the database?

Tags: mysql, web-services, hibernate

When I made direct changes in the database, it's not reflected in the webservices response on request, however it is working once I restart the server. How can I make changes work immediately?

My hibernate configuration file looks like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxxx</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxx</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: hibernate is too lazy to figure it by itself

Comment: Your cache is stale.

Comment: How can I make changes work immediately? without restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have use_second_level_cache set to true.
Change the value of use_second_level_cache to false and would hit db every time without using 2nd level cache